# How to name filename parameter to make clear it should contain full path?

Tags: naming, file-handling, conventions

I'm seeking vital naming of string `filename` parameter in parameter list used in various methods where **filename with full path** is expected. In many cases also UNC path can be actually supplied as full path because many libraries handle it natively.

I usually call the parameter just `filename`, but it can be misleading in two ways:

- Beginners tend to think it is only name of file – without path.
- If there is a need of splitting the value into path and filename, term **filename** sticks better with filename part without path which appeared after split. Anyway, it is not easy to give that second part better name than `filename`. Alternative of splitting `filename` to `path` and `filenameOnly` looks weird to me.

I think it might be better to use clearly distinguishable term for filename with path than borrowing **filename** which already has stronger meaning for something else.

I was thinking about term `absoluteFilePath` or `fullyQualifiedFilename` to stand as argument names. Maybe they are good and I need only some encouragement to start using them, but I would like to understand your best practices.

**EDIT:** I would still like to stick with official VB.NET [naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b283bse.aspx) and [capitalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b283bse.aspx) conventions, so the only thing I need help sharpening is clear self-documenting wording of the term. (Not whether I should use Hungarian notation or not – I cannot.)

Comment: `fullPath` sounds good to me.

Comment: @Brandon - if someone instantly reads list of parameters, seeing `fullPath` won't necessarily tell him 'file goes here'. Following your idea, `fullFilePath` or `fullPathToFile` might be better

Comment: Though, in my experience, then technical terms you're looking for here are `relative` and `absolute` paths.

Comment: @MetaFight - basically I agree, my comment was addressing another aspect of name creation in hope it could help someone

Comment: to downvoters: besides downvoting, please leave comment (this is recommended SE practice) how the question can be improved or if you think it is off-topic, please state why. For me and some other users discussing this was useful.

Comment: at on-hold: Currently I'm using VB.NET, there is not a big maneuvring space for naming a variable so I would object *on-hold*. Official guidelines give strict [naming conventions](http://bit.ly/1i6Esfg) and [capitalization conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx). Only **one form** of capitalization and noun/verb usage remains legitimate. I was asking about best *wording* (final constraint) in exact use case. There could be (and were) 2-3 relatively similar suggestions, but not diametrally different opinions. So this is not typical opinion-based Q with vast choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be safer defining a code contract.

You can say a precondition of this method is that the path supplied is an *absolute* path.

You can make this clearer by naming the input parameter `String absolutePathToFile`.

And finally, you can make your method fail early if the preconditions aren't met.  Do this by checking if the `absolutePathToFile` is indeed an absolute path.  If not, throw an argument exception.

So, instead of simply picking a parameter name and hoping the next developers a) pay attention to it, and b) understand it the same way you do (both of which are unlikely), you do the following:

1. **Code Contract**: Explicitly declare your method preconditions.  You can put this in your documentation, or as inline method documentation (if your language/ide supports it)
2. **Self Documenting Code**: Choose a parameter name that describes what you want as clearly as possible (not always easy)
3. **Defensive Programming**: Check your method parameters to see if they're valid.  If not, fail hard and fail early.

Comment: In rare cases, filename without path can be supplied, too. Underlying libraries can handle it and I do not want to artifically prevent this. If filename without path is supplied then path of currently launched executable is assumed. At the moment I cannot afford testing wave triggered by suggested modification – because of large size of the application. (I only joined the work on existing project.) But generally your idea of code contracts is good, I appreciate it. `String absolutePathToFile` is also a good idea.

Comment: I'd advise against building your system to *implicitly* support rare cases.  If these cases are known, then detect them and normalize the data so that it becomes the general case.  In your example, maybe you should check the nature of the path *before* calling your function.  If it's just a filename, then convert it to an absolute path of that filename in the launched executable's folder.  This way your method's concern is still just absolute paths, and your known rare case is addressed as well.

Comment: "In rare cases, filename without path can be supplied, too." - honestly, the way you describe this in your comment, it sounds like you just want to use the standard convention of standard file ops: when no full path is supplied, the partial path is not absolute, but relative to the current directory of the current process or thread. If that's true, a name like `absolutePathToFile` would be pretty misleading.

Comment: @MetaFight – I will go with your recommendations, implementing them in long-term change cycle. Thank you again.

Comment: @DocBrown – **My conclusion after some time has passed:** I have considered DocBrown's comment, too – it has a good point. Where the parameter is subject of processing only by generic file functions which do not necessarily require absolute path (and where I won't implement the enforcement of absolute path), I will name it `pathToFile` (including derived forms like `pathToSettingsFile` or `pathToFileFromWebservice` etc.). I will use `absolutePathToFile` (`absolutePathToSettingsFile`, `absolutePathToFileFromWebservice`, ...) only where absolute path is a strict requirement.